# How do I read a video from a webcam with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I'm following [the official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), trying to read a video from a webcam. As I run the piece of code from the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it fails with the following output:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9748
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "capture.py", line 11, in 
>       gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>   cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Inspecting it further, it appears that:

- `ret` is always `False`.
- Adding `cap.get(3)` (to get the width of the picture) returns `0.0`.
- If I test `cap.isOpened()`, the result is always `False`.
- If I add a call to `cap.open(0)`, `open` returns `False` as well.
- Calling `cap.open("/dev/video0")` changes nothing.
- Replacing `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` by `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")` has no effect.

Opening `/dev/video0` in VLC shows the video from the webcam. When I open Cheese, it also shows the video from the webcam. There is only one camera connected to the PC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How have you installed opencv? What is your OS? What version of python do you use?

Comment: How have you installed Opencv ?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I installed OpenCV (and also reinstalled it once to be sure). Since I posted the question, I tried the C++ sample, and it works. I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu, and Python 3.

Comment: You have compiled it from the source code, or you have installed it from the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I compiled it from the source code, following the instructions from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing FFMPEG. OpenCV needs the codec information to decode the videos, open cameras, etc which ffmpeg provides.

The steps to install FFmpeg on Windows are detailed here http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows. Following the Linux equivalent of this might solve your problem

Comment: Did you install opencv using pip or Anaconda?